# How to include Node and/or Ruby as part of NuGet package?

Tags: ruby, windows, node.js, visual-studio, nuget

**The use case**

Let's say I want to convert a Ruby Gem or Node.JS NPM package into a NuGet package, and I don't want the consumer of the package (and the build environment) to have to install Node.JS or Ruby, how would I do that?

**In particular**

How to obtain/make a portable / x-copy-deployable version of Node.JS/Ruby that I can just copy in the package folder and call from it?

**I know it's doable**

[Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) Visual Studio extension, and some NuGet packages, like [node-jshint](https://www.nuget.org/packages/node-jshint) seem to do that, but I can't tell exactly what steps I'd need to do for that.

**Any idea / guide?**

Comment: Can you link to the NuGet packages you've seen in the wild doing this?

Comment: This one seems to https://www.nuget.org/packages/node-jshint and also Web Essentials does it I think.

Answer (score 0):

The `node-jshint` package isn't a good example of this because it's structure is a bit off so it doesn't get all these benefits, but there's three things you need to do to integrate external tools into the Package Manager Console:

- Add the relevant tools into your `tools` folder for the NuGet package. So node.exe and other scripts the user needs are not considered libraries or content. How to make the tools be bin-deployable will depend from stack to stack, but here's a [blog post going into details for Ruby](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2010/03/23/running-ruby-and-rake-and-albacore-without-installing-them/) but it's essentially [download and unpack the 7zip archive from rubyinstaller.org](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)...
- A script named `tools\init.ps1` - this runs before the other Powershell scripts, and whenever the solution is opened in VS. It needs this line at the header because conventions (more details on these scripts [here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Automatically_Running_PowerShell_Scripts_During_Package_Installation_and_Removal))

`param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)`

- A function that the user can run. This is a simple example:

  ```
  param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

  function Enable-DoSomething {
      [CmdletBinding()]
      param (
         [Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromPipeLine=$true)]
         [string] $ProjectName
      )

      # do something cool here like invoke node.exe from under the tools dir 
      Write-Host "Hello $ProjectName from $toolsPath"
  }

  Export-ModuleMember Enable-DoSomething
  ```

The `Export-ModuleMember` method makes it available to the user - by default functions are not visible...

Comment: I wrote this question after I felt the NuGet package was not enough, although I couldn't prove it. I'm not worried about calling the tools or enabling them in package console (the idea is that the NuGet package can call code that `Process.Start()`s the NPM/gem package), and the question is how to make a portable runtime folder to use.

Comment: You know, how to make a portable Node.JS/Ruby runtime folder to include in the Tools Nuget package folder.

Comment: For ruby, you can unpack the 7zip archive from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ and add that folder to your $PATH. Here's a good explanation of it: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2010/03/23/running-ruby-and-rake-and-albacore-without-installing-them/

Comment: The steps should be even easier for nodejs, but I can't reach npmjs.org to confirm that there's a standalone binary for it. Same trick as what they're doing in node-jshint...